# JPA, Hibernate, Java. Composite primary key, one of them is also foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key

I have a problem described shortly in the title. Can anyone tell me, how can I get the same database using JPA?

```
create table ALBUM
( 
 IdAlbum int, 
 AlbumName varchar(35) not null, 
 UrlOfAlbum varchar(60) not null,
 Primary Key(IdAlbum) 
);
create table ARTIST
(
 IdArtist int, 
 ArtistName varchar(35) not null, 
 Primary Key(IdArtist) 
);
create table TRACK
(
 IdTrack int,
 IdAlbum int,
 IdArtist int,
 TrackName varchar(35) not null,
 Primary Key(IdTrack, IdAlbum),
 Foreign Key(IdAlbum) references Album(IdAlbum),
 Foreign Key(IdArtist) references Artist(IdArtist)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the columns into embedded key and keep relationship in the main class:

```
@Embeddable
class TrackId
{
    private Integer idAlbum;
    private Integer idTrack;
    // getters, setters, equals and hashCode
}

@Entity
class Track
{
     @EmbeddedId
     TrackId trackId;

     @ManyToOne
     @MapsId("idAlbum")
     @JoinColumn(name = "idAlbum", referencedColumnName = "idAlbum")
      private Album album = null;

      ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a composite-id class using `@javax.persistence.Embeddable`

```
@Embeddable
public class TrackPK {
    @Column(name = "IdTrack")
    private Integer trackId;
    @JoinColumn(name = albumId, referencedColumnName = "IdAlbum")
    private Album album;
    // setters & getters
    // you also have to implement equals and hashCode
}
```

From then on there are two ways. You can use a `TrackPK` object inside your `Track` class with the `@EmbeddedId` annotation (as Vyskovsky suggested), or you can use `@IdClass(TrackPK.class)` outside your `Track` along with the `@Entity` annotation. You would also have to duplicate the fields and setters from the `TrackPK` class in `Track`, and use the same implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` for the `Track` class, and add the `@Id` annotation on both fields.

I know It sounds like a lot, but it's just copy-pasting the entire TrackPK innards and it turns `track.getTrackPK().getAlbum()` into `track.getAlbum()`, saving you from even using that TrackPK class directly. You can just let the JPA handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "derived identity":

```
@Entity
public class Album {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "IdAlbum")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "AlbumName")
    private String name;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class TrackID {
    @Column(name = "IdTrack")
    private Integer trackID;

    @Column(name = "IdAlbum")
    private Integer albumID; // NB: corresponds to PK type of Album

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Track {
    @EmbeddedId
    TrackID id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("albumID") // NB: maps 'albumID' attribute of embedded id
    @JoinColumn(name = "IdAlbum", referencedColumnName = "IdAlbum")
    private Album album;

    ...
}
```

Derived identities are discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.